# How to assign and use multiple values in a variable in a case statement?

Tags: bash

the user would input 1-8 different value/values to get one or more outputs
ex: 
user inputs "1 3 5"
output:
one
three
five

how would this be done?

```
read -p "1-8" one two three four five six seven eight

all = ($one $two $three $four $five $six $seven $eight)

case $all in
   1) echo "one";;
   2) echo "two";;
   3) echo "three";;
   4) echo "four";;
   5) echo "five";;
   6) echo "six";;
   7) echo "seven";;
   8) echo "eight";;
esac;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a loop, and it would be simpler to read directly into an array:

```
read -p "1-8" -ra values
for x in "${values[@]}"; do
    case $x in 
      1) echo "one" ;;
      # etc
    esac
done
```

Another array would be even simpler than a `case` statement:

```
numbers=(zero one two three four five six seven eight)
read -p "1-8" -ra values
for x in "${values[@]}"; do
    echo "${numbers[x]}"
done
```

Comment: minor suggestion: `echo "${numbers[x]:-unknown}"`